# Shape and dimensions of the Moon's reference surface for selenographic latitude/longitude?

Tags: the-moon, coordinates

For Earth, the reference surface for "GPS" latitude, longitude, and altitude is the [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#Longitudes_on_WGS_84) ellipsoid, with equatorial and polar radii $a, b$ of 6378.1370 and 6356.7523 kilometers, respectively. Altitudes are calculated as the distance from a point to this reference surface along a line normal to the surface, *not along a line from the geocenter*. Math is given in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27194/12102).

Does the Moon's selenographic coordinate system have a reference surface? Is it a sphere or an ellipsoid or something else? What are it's dimensions?

I've looked in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenographic_coordinates), and in

- [A Standardized Lunar Coordinate System for the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://lunar.gsfc.nasa.gov/library/451-SCI-000958.pdf)
- [Determination of Selenographic Positions](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1971Moon....2..293M)
- [Selenographic Control](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1973Moon....8..461M)

but these are not helpful and the Moon's "selenography" has been evolving as lunar exploration and metrology has increased over time.

**Question:** What are the dimensions and shape of the Moon's reference surface for selenographic latitude/longitude?

---

**below:** exaggerated illustration of Earth's ellipsoid, from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:WGS84_mean_Earth_radius.svg).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's precisely one selenographic coordinate system, but section 2.3 of the [Lunar Constants and Models Document (JPL D-32296)](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/lunar_cmd_2005_jpl_d32296.pdf) seems to recommend spheres.

> 2.3  Moon Shape Parameters
>
> The general shape of the Moon is very nearly a perfect sphere,
>   excluding local topography variations.  In fact, the magnitude of the
>   local topography variations are much larger than the overall
>   flattening of the lunar poles or any ellipticity of the lunar equator.
>   Based upon the data presented in Reference 7, the magnitude of the
>   lunar flattening relative to the equatorial radius is about 2 km. 
>   This memo, however, recommends representing the verall shape of the
>   Moon for any mission design and navigation analyses as a  perfect
>   sphere

It goes on:

> $R_{Moon-Equator}$
>   = 1737.4 km  (Radius of Moon equator from IAU/IAG)
>
> $R_{Moon-Pole}$
>   = 1737.4 km  (Radius of Moon pole from IAU/IAG)
>
> $f_{Moon}$
>   = 0.0  (Moon flattening factor, derived from IAU/IAG values)

Terrain elevations in section 2.6.1 are referenced to the same sphere; altitude for many applications could be taken with reference to those elevations.

Comment: Thanks! That's now 13 years old, and even predates the launch of the [Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Reconnaissance_Orbiter). Presumably LRO data is available in a well defined, coordinate system. If LRO data has latitude and longitude, then whatever surface is used for that might be a good answer.

Comment: :/  this answer "might be a good answer..."  The LRO data http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/lro/default.htm isn't really monolithic, and understanding it isn't something I want to spend a lot of time on, though the LOLA experiment's height data uses an offset of 1737400.  http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/lro/lola_faq.htm

Comment: It may in fact be the best answer, I'll keep looking around as well. So far I found the bottom of [this page](http://ode.rsl.wustl.edu/moon/pagehelp/quickstartguide/index.html?coordinate_system.htm) links to a 2008 LRO document [A Standardized
Lunar Coordinate System for the
Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter
and Lunar Datasets ](https://lunar.gsfc.nasa.gov/library/LunCoordWhitePaper-10-08.pdf) but which still says *"The existing lunar reference frames that define the coordinates of surface features are expected to
undergo improvement, some significantly, during the LRO mission..."*

Comment: *"...as a result of the measurements and observations LRO is expected to acquire."*