# Deviation of semi-major axis

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

If I calculate the semi-major axis of Molniya-1T with
$a = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{GM}{n^2}}$ with $n=3.18683728\text{ }d^{-1}$, I get another [apoapsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) ($a=19505.7$ km) as noted at [Heavens Above](https://heavens-above.com/orbit.aspx?satid=24960&lat=-35.32&lng=149.008&loc=Mt.%20Stromlo%2C%20Australia&alt=0&tz=AEST&cul=en):

> apogee height:     25659 km
>
> perigee height:     595 km

which is $a=\frac{25659+595}{2}=13127$ km.

This is my approach in Octave/MATLAB:

```
# Computes the semi major axis a from n with constant GM
# @params:
#   GM constant (cubic km per square second)
#   n: mean motion  (revs/day)
# @return:
#   a: semi major axis (km)

function a = getSemiMajorAxis(GM,n)
  n = n*2*pi/(24*60*60); #conversion (revs/day) --> (rad/s)
  a = (GM/(power(n,2))).^(1./3);
endfunction

getSemiMajorAxis(398600.44,3.18683728) # Test with Molniya-1T
```

So, what is the origin of the deviation? Isn't apogee the same as apoapsis basically?

Comment: I saw your profile; here are some geoinformatics questions you might find interesting: [Shape and dimensions of the Moon's reference surface for selenographic latitude/longitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27359/12102) and [How do we define geographical coordinates on non-spheroid celestial bodies?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21278/12102)

Answer (score 10):

Ok, that's embarrassing:

You just have to add earth's radius (traditionally the [equatorial radius](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23847/12102)) of about 6378 or [6378.137](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/earthfact.html) km to apogee or perigee *heights* to get distances to the center.

Comment: An endless source of confusion. Get used to it :)

Comment: It's good that you wrote an answer, others may well have the same issue!

Comment: The clock in San Dimas, is always running... you have to dial one number higher.